# Running HQL using beeline doesn't work for INSERT INTO command

Tags: hive, dml, bigdata

I created a DML file and I'm trying to run it through beeline. The first command which is creating a table works but to insert values doesn't work. It looks like beeline doesn't wait for the result and exit right away.

This is my hql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS color_depth (
ID STRING ,
VALUE_1 STRING);
INSERT INTO TABLE color_depth VALUES ('1', '16 million (32-bit)'), ('2', '16 million (24-bit)'), ('3', '65,536 (16-bit)'), ('4', '256 (8-bit)'), ('5', '16 (4-bit)'), ('6', '4 (2-bit)'), ('8', '32,768 (15-bit)'), ('11', 'Monochrome'), ('13', 'Monochrome'), ('17', '4 (2-bit)'), ('27', '4,096 (12-bit)'), ('28', '256'), ('29', '???'), ('30', '???'), ('31', '???'), ('32', '???'), ('33', '???'), ('34', '???'), ('35', '???'), ('36', '???'), ('37', '???'), ('38', '???'), ('39', 'Offline Data Import');
```

And this is the command I run

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hive-server:10000 -f color_depth.hql
```

This is the results I got.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://hive-server:> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS color_depth (
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> ID STRING ,
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> VALUE_1 STRING);
No rows affected (0.386 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://hive-server:> INSERT INTO TABLE color_depth VALUES ('1', '16 million (32-bit)'), ('2', '16 million (24-bit)'), ('3', '65,536 (16-bit)'), ('4', '256 (8-bit)'), ('5', '16 (4-bit)'), ('6', '4 (2-bit)'), ('8', '32,768 (15-bit)'), ('11', 'Monochrome'), ('13', 'Monochrome'), ('17', '4 (2-bit)'), ('27', '4,096 (12-bit)'), ('28', '256'), ('29', '???'), ('30', '???'), ('31', '???'), ('32', '???'), ('33', '???'), ('34', '???'), ('35', '???'), ('36', '???'), ('37', '???'), ('38', '???'), ('39', 'Offline Data Import');
Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://hiver-server:10000
```

The CREATE TABLE works as expected. I can see that the table is created but the second command INSERT INTO that table doesn't work. I can't see any data in the table.

However, if I copy and paste the query to CLI it works as expected.

This is the specs of the software I use.

I'm using Amazon EMR 4.3.0 with Hive version 1.0.0 and Presto-sandbox 0.130

The beeline command I'm using from my local machine is

```
[bin] $ ./beeline --version
Hive 1.0.1
Subversion git://glacier.local/Users/chao/Documents/hive -r 73b600dc79ba8a9a32078a2ea0eb8ae3df20c9d5
Compiled by chao on Thu May 14 15:44:59 PDT 2015
From source with checksum 1876ce839dac365241a60e046443c00a
```

And I didn't use any SerDe. I'm trying to just create simple table and insert some data. It's going to be lookup data from Omniture.

Comment: Is there any relevant info you can share about: hive version? JDBC driver version *(for Beeline)*? default Hive execution engine (MapReduce, Tez, Spark)? ACID transaction setup *(since you appear to use that half-baked feature)*? Default table SerDe (Text, SequenceFile, ORC, Parquet)?

Comment: I've updated the question with the specs.

Comment: There *has to be* a default SerDe (i.e. Java classes for Serialization / De-Serialization). And the version from `hive-jdbc-*.jar` in the Beeline CLASSPATH is more relevant than the Beeline version itself -- but in your case it has to be the same version as the rest (Hive CLI, HiveServer2, etc.)